# How to cache three.js Object3D in cache?

Tags: javascript, collada

I am new to three.js and want to understand how can I cache the 3D models/Object3D to reduce the loading time of 3D models (collada)

I am using collada loader to load dae file in three.js based viewer. It works fine but I also want to understand how can I cache the model so that model picks it from disk cache and not load the entity again to reduce the loading time.

[image: collada model not loading from disk cache]

Comment: You'll need to check the cache headers on the model file. If the server says it may not be cached, it won't be cached.

Comment: @AKX I did checked the headers on model file and there is no such property set.
I have seen for binary files loading the models get cached like for kmz or glb but for ASCII files it doesn't.

Comment: Then configure your server to serve those headers.